# Non-catchable FileNotFoundException when using XmlReader.Create

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

I am currently designing a program where a string array saves every time a button is pushed and loads at the start of the program. I have two issues: one, when trying to load the file, it hits the using statement and it gives me the exception of `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. Later after the third button pushed, it gives me the exception of `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` and crashes with a `System.Exception`. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Note: this runs on Windows 8.

```
public static void excecuteload()
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
        string[] loadednames;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("filenamestr")) //Causes an exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        {
            loadednames = (string[])ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        names = (string[])loadednames.Clone();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ;
    }
}
public async static void excecutesave()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
        XmlWriterSettings setstr = new XmlWriterSettings();
        setstr.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        XmlObjectSerializer serializerstr = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string[])); //Gives error of System.UnauthorizedAccessException on the third go through
        Stream streamstr = await folder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("filenamestr", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        XmlWriter writerstr = XmlWriter.Create(streamstr, setstr);
        serializerstr.WriteObject(writerstr, names);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageDialog oops = new MessageDialog("Oops... we couldn't save your score :(");
        oops.ShowAsync();
     }
}
```

Comment: Note how I updated the title and refined the tags. There is no need to worry about "Serialization" when the file can't be read by XmlReader. Focus on and report the *immediate* problem (and only ask about *one* problem/question per post) - also, generally Exceptions aren't considered "crashes". I have no idea what the UnauthorizedAccessException exception is about, but see above.

Comment: erro explain itself.FileNotFoundException so check your path

Comment: No, it actually crashed the program, despite having a catch

Comment: @user3439632 Ahh, that's indeed .. curious. (If the question is about that specifically, make sure to isolate it from everything else.)

Answer (score 0):

create an XML file called `filenamestr` in your programs working directory.

If you want to create a file called  `filenamestr.xml` instead, than you have to change the using statement.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("filenamestr.xml"))
```

Comment: I might be able to edit this answer to be more useful if you edit your question to tell us why you think that the file ought to be found in wherever your program is looking for it.